# What do i need to build a web app like Shopify or Wix?

Tags: web, web-applications, shopify

I really want to build a Web app, where you can build your own Website, because it would help many people to get a website and it would help my wallet. But i have NO clue how to start, where to start, which langauges would be the best for that and which programming environment (react or angular or ruby on rails, smth like that).
Does anyone know how to build that stuff or how he would build that?

Thx,
Hope you have great Day

-Lockz

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you want to start you can check this repository which is an open source alternative to Shopify's built-in react you can check the code there [Shopify Alternative Medusa](https://github.com/medusajs/medusa)